# Javascript for showing random images is not working

Tags: javascript, vanilla-forums

The context of this script is that its meant to show a random image everytime a user opens the page. But it is not doing that. I am proficient with Java and C so javascript is coming off a little shady to me right now. Here is my javascript code:

```
<script>
var imgArray = ["test1.jpg", "test2.jpg", "test3.jpg", "test4.jpg"];
var basePath="/home/compdirl/public_html/vanilla/imagesAds/";

function imgRandom() {

        var rand = imgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length)];
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = basePath+rand;
        document.body.appendChild(image);

}

imgRandom();
</script>
```

Why would this script not be working? I am trying to place it on my forum for ads , but it will only show up on one area and none of the images even load. What's going on - is itan issue with my code or images?

Comment: You seem to be using the server's entire filesystem's root as the base path. `public_html` is probably the document root so try just `var basePath="/vanilla/imagesAds/";`

Comment: Wow! I figured I had addressed that possible issue of it not knowing where the directory was by including the full directory name. I did what you said and it is working. Very interesting.

I figure you should put that comment as an answer, despite how simple a fix it was?

Comment: I'd like to ask - is my code still not 'competent'? It seems that the images will only appear in specific areas of my site. Is there a reason for that? Like perhaps I'm not effectively appending an image ors omething.